# How to get the encoder part of a neural network in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, resnet

I want to apply transfer learning (initiate the encoder of my custom net with the weights from a pre-trained encoder of UNet or ResNet). So the queation is:
Given an instance of UNet or ResNet in Pytorch, how to extract the encoder part of a ResNet or UNet in PyTorch?

[This blog](https://medium.com/the-owl/extracting-features-from-an-intermediate-layer-of-a-pretrained-model-in-pytorch-easy-way-62631c7fa8f6) shows a way to do it, but it requirs me to have the class of UNet or ResNet at first which is not practical for me. Because the instance of UNet or ResNet is obtained by a function like: `net = get_resnet(depth=34)`, I can only get the instance of UNet or ResNet but I can not get the class of them.

Answer (score 0):

For ResNet the final layer is simply `self.fc`, so if you instantiate a ResNet model, you can redefine `self.fc` to your preferred classification task, keeping the rest of the model intact, including pretrained weights if applicable.

For UNet, this is a little trickier, because the decoder consists of upsampling layers as well as the output layer, but the same can be done replacing `self.up1`, `self.up2`, `self.up3`, `self.up4`, and `self.outc`.

Be sure to replace the layers after loading weights.